# How to work with mysql cursor when you are dealing with a huge number of columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor, relational-database, rdbms

I am writing a procedure to convert data from multiple smaller tables into a 'flat' table with many columns(~100).

I have a cursor defined which reads/joins data from smaller tables.

So far I have seen that 'fetch' semantics works with explicit variables in mysql. Is there a way where I can do something like: 'fetch * from cursor; followed by insert'?

Following is a sample (for single field insert).

How to deal if let's say temp and jsontable had 50 columns. (fetching into 50 explicit variables or is there a better way?)

[Oracle has something called 'BULK COLLECT']

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc_insert (OUT param1 INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

declare iden int;

declare msg JSON;

declare insertCursor cursor for select * from temp;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

open insertCursor;

read_loop: LOOP

FETCH insertCursor INTO iden,msg;

IF done THEN

LEAVE read_loop;

END IF;

insert into jsontable(jdoc) values(msg);

END LOOP;

close insertCursor;

END
```

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea

Comment: why so? and what alternative would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest a normalised design (3NF)

Comment: There is a normalized design. This flat table is for reporting purpose and not part of application transaction!!

Comment: Fair enough.!!!

Comment: Do you absolutely have to do this in straight SQL? There's a case for a programming language here, I'd say (in particular, this sort of thing becomes quick and easy when you add PHP arrays to the mix). Or, if you /have/ to stay in SQL, how about a stored procedure that uses the table metadata to construct SQL statements in a loop?

Comment: Since you are going to execute the whole table without any `where clause` instead of executing `select * from temp` and inserting inside a cursor it's better to insert the whole table with a simple `Insert`?

Comment: I haven't mentioned in the example but there is a where clause

Comment: How about temp table insertion?